# C# WPF Unable to write to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am new to WPF and am attempting to write a child node to an XML file.  Here is the file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <LastSavedSequence name="Last Saved Sequence">    
     <Test name="Measure Battery Current(Stim)" testNumber="5" Vbat="3.7" Frequency="20" PulseWidth="500" Amplitude="1" Resistance="1600" Anode="1" Cathode="2" ActiveDischarge=""/>
     <Test name="Measure Batther Current(No Stim)" testNumber="6" Vbat="2.9" Frequency="20" PulseWidth="500" Amplitude="1" Resistance="1600" Anode="1" Cathode="2" ActiveDischarge=""/>
  </LastSavedSequence>  
  <ScottTestSequence name="Scott Test Sequence">    
     <Test name="VMO Status" testNumber="4" Vbat="3.7" Frequency="20" PulseWidth="1000" Amplitude="6" Resistance="3000" Anode="1" Cathode="2" ActiveDischarge=""/>
     <Test name="Measure Battery Current(Stim)" testNumber="5" Vbat="3.7" Frequency="20" PulseWidth="500" Amplitude="1" Resistance="1600" Anode="1" Cathode="2" ActiveDischarge=""/>
     <Test name="Measure Batther Current(No Stim)" testNumber="6" Vbat="2.9" Frequency="20" PulseWidth="500" Amplitude="1" Resistance="1600" Anode="1" Cathode="2" ActiveDischarge=""/>
  </ScottTestSequence>  
</Sequences>
```

I am attempting to create an XML child block to go within .  I used stringBuilder and then am trying to do an attach child and then a .save.  XMLData2 is a global list and contains a the child elements that I get in the for each.  Here is my code...

```
public static List<System.Xml.XmlNode> xmlData2 = new List<System.Xml.XmlNode>();
XmlDocument xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.Load("c:\\Users/StarkS02/Documents/SavedSequenceFile.xml");
StringBuilder exampleNode = new StringBuilder();
                        exampleNode.Append("<");
                        exampleNode.Append(tbSequenceName.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", ""));
                        exampleNode.Append(" name=");
                        exampleNode.Append("'");
                        exampleNode.Append(tbSequenceName.Text);
                        exampleNode.Append("'");
                        exampleNode.Append(">");
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlData2)
                        {
XmlElement child = xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.CreateElement(string.Empty, node.OuterXml, string.Empty);
exampleNode.Append("</");
                        exampleNode.Append(tbSequenceName.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", ""));
                        exampleNode.Append(">");
xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.AppendChild(exampleNode);
xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.Save("c:\\Users/StarkS02/Documents/SavedSequenceFile.xml");
```

I get a compiler error on the .appendChild statement that I cannot convert a stringBuilder to an XML node.  This makes sense but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Tags are used here to find questions we can answer. This is a .NET XML question; it has nothing to do with WPF. And the “Save” tag doesn’t have much to do with it either; not body is a general expert in “saving stuff” in any way that’s useful here. Please only use tags that will attract the attention of people knowledgeable about the problem you’re having.

Comment: Why convert the string element to xml.  Just use StreamWriter to write the string to a file.  Xml methods in Net expect only a single element at the root which is referred to as "Well Formed".  When you have multiple elements at root you do not have "Well Formed" and will get an error.  So just use StreamWriter which will take any data and write to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an XML fragment and append to the document.

```
var xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile = new XmlDocument();
xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.Load("c:\\Users/StarkS02/Documents/SavedSequenceFile.xml");
```

See here for more on DocumentFragment

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createdocumentfragment(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var fragment = xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.CreateDocumentFragment();
fragment.InnerXml = @"<somexml></somexml>";
xmlFromOutSideSequenceFile.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(fragment);
```

See here for more on XMLNode

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx

Decide where you want to put it.
    .FirstChild
    .LastChild
    .NextSibling
    .ParentNode
    .PreviousSibling

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ScottS if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.